# BS4 in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have recently tried to install BS4 in Python 2.7.13 on my PC. Installation process appears to work perfectly, but when I try to import bs4 I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
I have tried to reinstall it several times using pip and/or easyinstall. Example below:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install bs4
Searching for bs4
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/bs4/
Downloading 
https://pypi.python.org/packages/10/ed/7e8b97591f6f456174139ec089c76
9f89a94a1a4025fe967691de971f314/bs4-
0.0.1.tar.gz#md5=fe7e51587ac3b174608f3c4f8bd
893ac
Best match: bs4 0.0.1
Processing bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\kloc\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-1g2akp\bs4-
0.0.1\setup.cfg

Running bs4-0.0.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir 
c:\users\kloc\appdata\local\t
emp\easy_install-1g2akp\bs4-0.0.1\egg-dist-tmp-gxksva
warning: install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to 
install


zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Moving bs4-0.0.1-py2.7.egg to c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Adding bs4 0.0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\bs4-0.0.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for bs4
Searching for beautifulsoup4
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/
Downloading 
https://pypi.python.org/packages/fa/8d/1d14391fdaed5abada4e0f63543fe
f49b8331a34ca60c88bd521bcf7f782/beautifulsoup4-
4.6.0.tar.gz#md5=c17714d0f91a23b7
08a592cb3c697728
Best match: beautifulsoup4 4.6.0
Processing beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\kloc\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dw_u0f\beautifulsoup4-
4.6.
0\setup.cfg
Running beautifulsoup4-4.6.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir 
c:\users\kloc\appd
ata\local\temp\easy_install-dw_u0f\beautifulsoup4-4.6.0\egg-dist-tmp-oxng7i
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Moving beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py2.7.egg to c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Adding beautifulsoup4 4.6.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py2.7.egg
Finished processing dependencies for bs4
```

Installing with pip also works fine. I have also tried to do it using beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py2-none-any.whl file. Every time it seems to install without problems and then I can't seem to be able to import it. The BS4 files are present in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages. Yes, I have checked numerous other answers but nothing works for me. To add an insult to injury I have managed to pull it of on my laptop yesterday without (much) hassle. Can anyone please help me with solving that problem ?

Comment: Do you need to add it to your dependencies?

Comment: Unfortunately I am a complete beginner and have no idea what dependencies are and if I need them or not :/

Comment: try "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs"

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it after getting back from work and let you know what happened.